# Using the integral equation, find the eigenvalues and eigenfucntions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, integral-equations

The integral equation:
$$
\int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}}dt' \phi (t')e^{\Gamma\left | t-t' \right |}  =\lambda  \phi(t)
$$

for  $(-\frac{1}{2}T< t < \frac{1}{2}T)$

is useful in photon counting statistics theory.

Show that the eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ of the above equation are given by
$$
\Gamma \lambda_k  =  \frac{2}{1+u^{2}_k}
$$

where the $u_k$ are the roots of the transcendental equation

$$
tan(\Gamma T u_k) = \frac{2 u_k}{u^{2}_k - 1}
$$

Using this solve for the eigenfunctions associated

---

The $\Gamma$ here is a constant.  I can see that the kernel is an exponential.  I've worked this numerous times using Fredholms technique but repeatidly hit a brick wall.  Am I missing something?